# Group function is not allowed here

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

When I run the following query, I get

> ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here

what is the problem ?

```
select c.Numcom,c.Nompr,c.salaire_fix
from commercialv c,comercialv c1
where c.salaire_fix=(max(c1.salaire_fix) );
```

Comment: First i think you missed a join, second you should get the max as a subquery

Answer (score 18):

You cannot use an aggregate function in a `WHERE` clause.

Given your use case, you probably want a subquery:

```
select c.Numcom,c.Nompr,c.salaire_fix
from commercialv c
where c.salaire_fix=(select max(salaire_fix) from comercialv);
```

---

The rational is that aggregate functions works on a *set*. The `WHERE` clause on the other hand, has only access to the data of *one row*.

Comment: why ( where c.salarie_fix = max(c.salaire_fix) )doesn't work or (having c.salarie_fix = max(c.salaire_fix)) work ???

Comment: `having` works over a *group*. `where` is for filtering individual ("input") rows.

Answer (score 3):

You can do what you want with analytic functions:

```
select Numcom, Nompr, salair_fix
from (select c.Numcom, c.Nompr, c.salaire_fix,
             max(c.salaire_fix) over () as maxs
      from commercialv c
     ) c
where c.salaire_fix = c.maxs;
```

As for your query, aggregation functions are not permitted in the `where` clause.

Comment: it's too bad `c.salarie_fix = max(c.salaire_fix) over ()` doesn't work

Comment: This option will generally perform better (it avoids a 2nd probe on the table).

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this query using `MAX()` as a window function (or analytic function if you prefer the Oracle lingo):

```
SELECT numcom, nompr, salaire_fix FROM (
    SELECT numcom, nompr, salaire_fix, MAX(salaire_fix) OVER ( ) AS max_salaire_fix
      FROM commercialv
) WHERE salaire_fix = max_salaire_fix;
```

You could also use `RANK()`:

```
SELECT numcom, nompr, salaire_fix FROM (
    SELECT numcom, nompr, salaire_fix, RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY salaire_fix DESC ) AS salaire_fix_rank
      FROM commercialv
) WHERE salaire_fix_rank = 1;
```

Or even `ROWNUM`:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT numcom, nompr, salaire_fix
      FROM commercialv
     ORDER BY salaire_fix DESC
) WHERE rownum = 1;
```

The only difficulty with the last is that it will get only one row even if there are additional rows with the maximum value of `salaire_fix`. The first two queries will get more than one row in that case.

Comment: why ( where c.salarie_fix = max(c.salaire_fix) )doesn't work or (having  c.salarie_fix = max(c.salaire_fix)) work ???

Comment: The first one won't work because aggregate functions (and window functions) don't work in the `WHERE` clause. The second won't work because you can't get `MAX(salaire_fix)` while grouping by `salaire_fix`. Really, the best way to achieve the result you want is to use analytic (window) functions as in my answer and @Gordon Linoff's. @Sylvain Leroux's will also work and has the advantage of being completely portable (e.g., to MySQL, which doesn't have window functions).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use group function in where clause so you can use having clause. Example:

```
SELECT DEPTNO,COUNT(*)
FROM EMP
GROUP BY DEPTNO
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

What I found with Oracle is that Oracle will not comply with group when only one column is required. I use this syntax:

```
SELECT count(column) as "Sum of Count in column", column from table where column = <some matching criteria> 
group by column order by count(column) DESC
```